# javascript array confusion between x = [x] && x.push(x) when var x;

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does case 1 give us :error: TypeError: x is undefined on line...

```js
//case 1
var x;
x.push(x);
console.log(x);
```

Why does case 2 shows us Array[undefined]  in console

```js
//case 2
var x;
var x = [x];
console.log(x);
```

What is the difference between this 2 cases ?

Comment: In case 1, `x` is undefined because it has no value. `push()` is an array method, while `typeof(x)` would return undefined. In case 2, `x` is still undefined in the first declaration. In the second declaration, you're making it an array, but give it an undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case one, the line `x.push(x);` will throw an error if `x` is not defined - you can't access properties of an `undefined` object, of course.

In case two, `x` is not defined at the point the line `x = [x];` is run, but you aren't trying to access any properties of `x` or anything like that - it's just an `undefined` value, which is OK. So, the expression `[x]` results in an array with one item, `x` (which is `undefined`), thus `[undefined]`.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to push anything values to `x`, you must first say that it is an array like this

```
var x = [];
```

About the variable is showing as undefined because any variable in javascript when no values is assigned to it is by default undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

You are trying to invoke `.push()` on `undefined`

```
var x; // x is declared but value is undefined
x.push(x); // .push() can be invoked only on array types - that's why you get the error
console.log(x); // error happens before this line
```

**Case 2**

`unndefined` is a value in JavaScript. You are creating an array with one entry - `undefined`.

```
var x; // x is undefined
var x = [x]; // x = [undefined] - an array with one entry - undefined
console.log(x); // prints the array
```

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings need to be explained:

1. When you declare a variable, `undefined` is the default value is been set. Until you set any other like `var x = '';`.
2. `[].push()` is only available on arrays.

So, in your both cases:

#### Case: 1

```
var x; // default value set to = undefined
x.push(x); // here push is undefined because undefined don't have push method.
console.log(x); // it doesn't executes because of breaking line of code above.
```

#### Case: 2

```
//case 2
var x; // default value set to = undefined
var x = [x]; // now x is converted to an array and reassigned to x.
console.log(x); // logs array of one undefined value.
```